# Compile errors when importing Cardano Serialization Lib Browser in React

Tags: wallet, cardano-serialization-lib, api, react

I'm getting several compile errors as soon as I import `@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser` in my project, all of them similar to these:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg.js 19251:82-105
Can't import the named export '__wbindgen_realloc' (imported as 'wasm') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg.js 19280:36-58
Can't import the named export '__wbindgen_malloc' (imported as 'wasm') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg.js 19280:60-83
Can't import the named export '__wbindgen_realloc' (imported as 'wasm') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg.js 19482:36-58
Can't import the named export '__wbindgen_malloc' (imported as 'wasm') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg.js 19482:60-83
Can't import the named export '__wbindgen_realloc' (imported as 'wasm') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg.js 19497:12-23
Can't import the named export 'memory' (imported as 'wasm') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)
```

Is there any other library I should use on a React project to handle wallet interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using dcSpark's Cardano Multiplatform Lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dcspark/cardano-multiplatform-lib-browser.